# How to negate the matcher in gtest assert or expect that?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd, googletest, assertions

I'd like to check if a vector is not empty in gtest but I'd like to understand more in general how to check the negation of a matcher.

I usually ckeck size is greater than zero

```
EXPECT_THAT( vector.size(), Gt( 0 ) );
```

and I know I could write my own matcher

```
MATCHER( IsNotEmpty, !negation ? "isn't empty" : "is empty" ) {
if ( !arg.empty() ) {
    return true;
}
*result_listener << "whose size is " << arg.size();
return false;
}
```

but I'm wondering if it's just simply possible to negate any matcher

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I find out that you can composite some matchers and do something like

```
EXPECT_THAT( vector, Not( IsEmpty() ) );
```

also other interesting composite matchers

```
AllOf(m1, m2, ..., mn)
AnyOf(m1, m2, ..., mn)
```